# App links not working on samsung and xiaomi phones

Tags: android, applinks, android-app-indexing

Set up app links to launch my app directly from a URL without showing a chooser dialog. Followed [android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) to make it work on some devices like pixel, oneplus, honor. But it does not work on samsung(s8, s6) and xiaomi devices.

When launching the app on compatible devices, I get these successful logs:

```
I/Finsky: [2184] zzj.b(3): Verify: Verification package=com.mycompany.customer, id=76 response=0
I/Finsky: [2178] aaev.b(4): PSIC verification started with installer uid: 2000 package name: null, originating uid: -1
I/Finsky: [2] aaam.c(5): Verifying id=76, result=1
I/Finsky: [2] aaam.ha(6): Verification complete: id=76, package_name=com.mycompany.customer
```

Samsung log on launching Url:

```
I/IntentFilterIntentOp: Verifying IntentFilter. verificationId:50 scheme:"https" hosts:"www.mycompany.com api.juspay.in sandbox.myClientcompany.in" package:"com.mycompany.customer".
```

Just no other logs about verification. Did anyone else face similar issues?
I keep getting intent chooser with default Browser as a choice along with my app.

=====

I spoke to the dev(@Google) concerned with this and it's a known compatibility issue. Samsung and Xiaomi have ignored this feature. App links don't work on all android phones.